# ANTLR4 does not throw expected error in presence of uninvolved rule

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have created an example grammar TestGrammar.g4 to illustrate my problem:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

Member_of : 'MEMBER OF';

Identifier : [a-z]+
           ;

WS: [ \n\t\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

parseSimpleExpression : (Identifier '.')+ Identifier
                      ;

collection_member_expression : parseSimpleExpression Member_of parseSimpleExpression
                            ;
```

Following code shows the invocation of the parser:

```
String expression = "x.a MEMBER OF y.a";
TestGrammarLexer l = new  TestGrammarLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(expression));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(l);
TestGrammarParser p = new TestGrammarParser(tokens);
p.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());
ParserRuleContext ctx = p.parseSimpleExpression();
```

My expectation is that ANTLR throws a syntax error on the input `x.a MEMBER OF y.a`, however
it does not. Instead it consumes only part of the input (`x.a MEMBER OF`) and finishes successfully.

Now, when I remove the last rule from the grammar, ANTLR throws a syntax error as expected. I don't understand this behaviour since the last grammar rule should not even be involved in the parsing since it is neither directly nor indirectly referenced by the start rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR isn't supposed to throw an exception. With the code:

```
String expression = "x.a MEMBER OF y.a";
TestGrammarLexer l = new  TestGrammarLexer(new ANTLRInputStream(expression));
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(l);
TestGrammarParser p = new TestGrammarParser(tokens);
p.setErrorHandler(new BailErrorStrategy());
ParserRuleContext ctx = p.parseSimpleExpression();
```

you're simply instructing ANTLR to parse `(Identifier '.')+ Identifier`, which it happily does since `"x.z"` is the first part of the input and matches the `parseSimpleExpression` production.

The fact that there are more tokens left in the token stream does not matter. If you want to make sure the entire input is consumed, you will need to *anchor* your rule with the `EOF` token:

```
parseSimpleExpression : (Identifier '.')+ Identifier EOF
                      ;
```

> *Moritz Becker wrote*
>
> *... however it does not. Instead it consumes only part of the input (x.a MEMBER OF) and ...*

No, that is not true, it only consumes `"x.a"` as you can verify yourself by printing what the context has matched:

```
System.out.println(ctx.getText()); // prints "x.a"
```

And if I remove the `collection_member_expression` rule from the grammar and regenerate the parser classes and rerun the the code above, it behaves exactly the same.

Comment: You are right, ANTLR only consumes `"x.a"`. However, I still don't see why leaving out the last rule `collection_member_expression` changes the behaviour of ANTLR and causes it to throw a syntax error. Is there a general way (apart from adding `EOF` to parser rules) to force ANTLR to parse the whole input string rather than just the first part that is accepted by the grammar?

Comment: No, if you want to for the parser to consume all the way to the end, you invoke a production/method that consumes all the way to the `EOF`. And I don't understand this part of your comment: *leaving out the last rule collection_member_expression changes the behaviour of ANTLR and causes it to throw a syntax error*. If by leaving out you mean removing, then I cannot reproduce that. Removing that parser rule or leaving it there makes no difference.